# How get CPU time (in milliseconds) of a process by ID

Tags: cpu

I'm running a website written in PHP on Ubuntu. I want to get the CPU time for a process (elapsed time since the process was started). I already have the process ID.

I know the ps command returns CPU time, but I only see in seconds. How can I get it in milliseconds?

The ps command I use:

```
$ ps -p 6176 -o etimes=
1020
```

Comment: `etimes` is not CPU time, it's the elapsed wall time. CPU time would be `time`. You can probably parse `/proc/<pid>/stat` for this information.

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
I show command like that: cat /proc/myId/stat, and I get cputime: total_time = utime + stime, but it is **second**, not **millisecond**.
I found : [/proc/pid/stat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726779/how-do-i-get-the-total-cpu-usage-of-an-application-from-proc-pid-stat)

Comment: utime and stime are in CPU clock ticks, not seconds.

Comment: I know cmd: **sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)** to get clock ticks by C (Hertz (number of clock ticks per second).
But in ubuntu or php, how I get it. Please help me.

Comment: and how I get millisecond ??

Comment: For a generic kernel a jiffy is 1/250 seconds, or 4 milliseconds. For a low latency kernel a jiffy is 1/1000 seconds, or 1 millisecond.

Comment: I use: grep 'CONFIG_HZ=' /boot/config-$(uname -r), and I get my Hertz  is: 250 (that is: 1/250 as **Doug Smythies** said).
 I  get the total elapsed time in seconds since the process started:
seconds = uptime - (starttime / Hertz)
But I alway get Negative Number.

Comment: thanks all, I solve my problem. I get worng ID, so the result is negative.
Thanks all. You save me.